# memory (re)allocation within func by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

for example:

```
void f(void *p) {
    p = malloc(1);
    printf("%i\n", p);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *p = malloc(1);
    printf("%i\n", p);
    f(p);
    printf("%i\n", p);
}
```

would produce something like this:

```
5513696
5513728
5513696
```

Why passing by address and allocating wouldn't change pointer address? 
p.s. where can be something like realloc (maybe even recursive realloc by recusrive function call)

Comment: as a side node, main should always return something, thus int main () and return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're passing the allocated memory by address but you're actually passing the *pointer* by value.

And it's the pointer you're changing in there but, since it's passed in by value, that change isn't reflected when you leave the function.

If you want to change the *pointer*, you have to pass yet another pointer to *it*, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f (void **p){
    // free (*p);         // add in to avoid memory leak
    *p = malloc (1);
    printf ("%i\n", *p);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    void *p = malloc (1);
    printf ("%i\n", p);
    f (&p);
    printf ("%i\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
6750728
6816336
6816336
```

as expected on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a pointer to a function you are copying by value, hence you are assigning a different pointer, which until you malloced, pointed to the same place as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Whn you call `p` it receives a copy of a pointer ("pass by value") which is discarded upon the function return. You could pass the pointer address instead.

```
void f(void** p){
  *p= ... whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
void f(void **p){
  *p=malloc(1);
  printf("%i\n",*p);
}

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  void *p=malloc(1);
  printf("%i\n",p);
  f(&p);
  printf("%i\n",p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a pointer as argument to a function a new pointer is created that points to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, you're passing the pointer by value. If you want to (re)allocate a pointer in a function, pass it by reference like so:

```
void f(void *& p)
```

Comment: There are no references in C _yet!_ :-) ISO should look very hard into adding them, they'd save an awful lot of problems with indirection.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way C function calls and the stack work. It might sound a bit tricky when written, I'm afraid.

First, the pointer `p-of-main` is allocated on the stack. Then, a function call is prepared. For this, all integral values have to be copied to the stack, so the value of `p-of-main` is copied and the function `f` is executed. Now f can only see the copied value in its argument space, but this is not the same memory location as `p-of-main`, it's actually a new "variable": `p-of-f`.

To achieve what you want to do you actually have to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer (I've marked the changed lines with `// !`):

```
void f(void **p){     // !
  *p=malloc(1);       // !
  printf("%i\n",*p);  // !
}

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  void *p=malloc(1);  // !
  printf("%i\n",p);
  f(&p);              // !
  printf("%i\n",p);
}
```